# How to chain two formulas in powerapps formula bar?

Tags: powerapps

In Powerapps I am creating a cascading list. There I want to combine two formulas. How can that be done?
I need to check two conditions on a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain formulas together with the ; operator within an argument to Concurrent. For example, Concurrent( Set( a, 1 ); Set( b, a+1 ), Set( x, 2 ); Set( y, x+2 ) ) evaluates Set( a, 1 ); Set( b, a+1 ) concurrently with Set( x, 2 ); Set( y, x+2 ). In this case, the dependencies within the formulas are fine: a will be set before b, and x will be set before y.